# Dart/Flutter Is there a way to find the index of my carousel?

Tags: flutter, dart, indexing, carousel

Is there a way to find the index of a carousel item so I can use it to retrieve the related text and link associated with the items shown??

So I have 3 lists, a list for images, a list for text, and a list for urls.

Is there a way to find the associated index/key to reuse??

```
         child: Container(
                      child: CarouselSlider(
                        options: CarouselOptions(
                          enlargeCenterPage: true,
                          enableInfiniteScroll: true,
                          autoPlay: true,
                          // pageSnapping: true,
                        ),
                        items: listThumbs.map((e) => ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                          child: Stack(
                            //fit: StackFit.expand,
                            children: <Widget>[
                            Image.network(e,
                            width: 1050,
                            height: 350,
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                          Text(videObj.results[INDEX].name),
                         ] ),
                        )).toList(),
                      )),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the builder method.

CarouselSlider [example](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider#build-item-widgets-on-demand)

```dart
CarouselSlider.builder(
  itemCount: 15,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int itemIndex, int pageViewIndex) =>
    Container(
      child: Text(itemIndex.toString()),
    ),
)
```

This method will give the `index` of every item.

Answer (score 1):

You can call 'indexOf' in the map iteration area.

```
int idx = listThumbs.indexOf(e);
```

```
         child: Container(
                      child: CarouselSlider(
                        options: CarouselOptions(
                          enlargeCenterPage: true,
                          enableInfiniteScroll: true,
                          autoPlay: true,
                          // pageSnapping: true,
                        ),
                        items: listThumbs.map((e) {
                          // Here you can find item index.
                          int idx = listThumbs.indexOf(e);

                          return ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                            child: Stack(
                              //fit: StackFit.expand,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Image.network(e,
                                  width: 1050,
                                  height: 350,
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                ),
                                Text(videObj.results[INDEX].name),
                              ]),
                             );
                            }
                          )).toList(),
                      )),
```